# How to open only camera and gallery using com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper library?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want set image validation like 72 ppi resolution and max size 100k so that I used [com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper](https://github.com/mitchtabian/AndroidImageCropper-Example) library in kotlin

I have used the below method for open direct camera or gallery and cropped image feature so that I can get all the options but I want to show only gallery and camera options, in which it shows drive options so it allow to choose other files also instead of images extension files only in drive.

```
CropImage.activity()
            .setRequestedSize(100,100)
            .setMaxCropResultSize(1000,1000)
            .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
            .setAspectRatio(100, 100)
            .setCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.RECTANGLE) 
            .start(this)
```

How can I prevent to show drive option in popup ?

Thanks in advance